# "You'll receive payment instructions via E-mail” payment method

Tags: payment, email

Due to various organizational reasons, it is not possible to determine the actual payment method during checkout. I need **empty payment** method, which just says you'll be informed within a hour.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way: Magento comes with a payment method called 'Check / Money order'. Just edit the title of that method and use it as an 'empty payment'. Check the `system->configuration->payment methods` section.

Comment: Ok, that might work. We will never accept checks, so I'd be ready to edit this module. I just want it to display some text instead of boxes for entering information, any idea how to do that?

Comment: Try what I said. The payment method has nothig to do with paychecks. It's just a simple option at the payment step in the checkout. The customer will see something like 'You will get the payment information by mail' and that's it. He will be able to go through the rest of the checkout process. Try it and see the results.

Comment: Ye, usually, when you set up Paychecks in backend, the custommer will get to see some information, like to whom write the check etc. I want to custommer see the message that they will get instructions via email. Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible. Do this: Set the title of the method to 'You will receive payment information by e-mail' and DON'T fill the fields 'Make Check Payable to' and 'Send Check to' and it should work. Just try it out and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

As Marius sayed, it the check payment is a very simple, almost empty one.

If check payment might still needed in additional as another payment method in the future, it is quite easy to create an own payment that is derived from the 'check / money order' payment, but this would need some coding.